# Lexical analysis

Tags: python, lexical-analysis, ply

I am learning lexers in Python. I am using Ply library for lexical analysis on some strings. I have implemented the following lexical analyzer for some of C++ language syntax.

However, I am facing a strange behavior. When I define the **COMMENT** `states function definitions` at the end of other function definitions, the code works fine. If I define **COMMENT** `state functions` before other definitions, I get errors as soon as `//` sectoin starts in the input string starts.

*WHAT IS THE REASON BEHIND THAT?*

```
import ply.lex as lex

tokens = (
        'DLANGLE',       # <<
        'DRANGLE',       # >>
        'EQUAL',        # =
        'STRING',       # "144"
        'WORD',         # 'Welcome' in "Welcome."
        'SEMICOLON',    # ;

)

t_ignore                = ' \t\v\r' # shortcut for whitespace


states = (
        ('cppcomment', 'exclusive'),   # <!--
)



def t_cppcomment(t): # definition here causes errors
    r'//'
    print 'MyCOm:',t.value

    t.lexer.begin('cppcomment');



def t_cppcomment_end(t):
    r'\n'
    t.lexer.begin('INITIAL');


def t_cppcomment_error(t):
    print "Error FOUND"
    t.lexer.skip(1)

def t_DLANGLE(t):

    r'<<'
    print 'MyLAN:',t.value
    return t

def t_DRANGLE(t):
    r'>>'
    return t

def t_SEMICOLON(t):

    r';'
    print 'MySemi:',t.value
    return t;

def t_EQUAL(t):
        r'='
        return t

def t_STRING(t):
        r'"[^"]*"'
        t.value = t.value[1:-1] # drop "surrounding quotes"
        print 'MyString:',t.value
        return t

def t_WORD(t):
        r'[^ <>\n]+'
        print 'MyWord:',t.value
        return t




webpage = "cout<<\"Hello World\"; // this comment"
htmllexer = lex.lex()
htmllexer.input(webpage)
while True:
        tok = htmllexer.token()
        if not tok: break
        print tok
```

Regards

Comment: Anybody some insight?

Comment: It might help if you posted a sample of your errors.

Comment: No interpreter errors are generated, as the errors are handled by t_cppcomment_error() module. My question is this error module isn't called if I define all teh comment modules in the end but it is called when comment modules are defined before other modules

Comment: you dont have any symbols defined for cppcomment state ... see my answer to define a symbol that works in that state to collect everything up to the end of the line ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley OK but if I define comment modules at the end, t_String() & t_word() are called, but they are not called when comment modules are defined at top Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. As I have defined comment state as `exclusive`, it won't use the `inclusive` state modules (if comment modules are defined at the top, otherwise it uses it for some reason). So you will have *redefine* all the modules for comment state again. Therefore **ply** provides **error()** modules for skipping characters for which specific modules are not defined.

Comment: this approach doesnt make any sense unless you want to enforce your language tokens on the comment ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Purpose of this question wasnt parsibg comments, the reason was to find why we get errors when are in exclusive states. :)

Answer (score 0):

its because you have no rules that accept `this` or `comment`
and really you dont care about whats in the comment you can easilly do something like

```
t_cppcomment_ANYTHING = '[^\r\n]'
```

just below your `t_ignore` rule

Comment: Aren't the `t_WORD()` or `t_String()` modules will be called? They are supposed to be called, as they were called for "Hello World" & cout ?

Comment: no .. t_STRING needs quotes , and t_WORD cant have spaces ... you could just try my solution and see that it solves your issue ... also Im not sure if states can recieve symbols that are not defined for that state

Comment: Just figured it out. As I have defined comment state as exclusive, it won't use the inclusive state modules (if comment modules are defined at the top, otherwise it uses it for some reason). So you will have redefine all the modules for comment state again. Therefore ply provides error() modules for skipping characters for which specific modules are not defined.

The purpose of this question was to figure out this reason.

Comment: why would you do that ? why not just grab the whole comment in a token rather than using the global tokens (comments should not have to match global syntax imho) ... this solution just captures the whole comment into its own token ...